# SPD2013: I need to get the checkoutusr of files checked out in my document library in my Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, web, service

I am using the Call HTTP Web Service inside of 2013 designer.  I can get my query to work, but once I try to add the person columns is where I fail.  It no longer runs.

I have tried so many things.  the column name is CheckoutUser in my library and my select in my request is below:

```
select=ID,Title,CheckoutUser/Name&$expand=CheckoutUser
```

Comment: Well it's working. exactly as coded above.  Selecting it into a variable simply uses d/results([Variable:Index%]/CheckoutUser/Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the answer above, aka
Well it's working. exactly as coded above. Selecting it into a variable simply uses d/results([Variable:Index%]/CheckoutUser/Name

Not certain what was going on.